# How to hide the last call from traceback?

Tags: python, error-handling, traceback

I have the following code

```py
def _raise_exception(exception):
    raise exception

def require_odd(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        _raise_exception(ValueError("n must be odd"))

print(require_odd(2))
```

When I run it, it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(require_odd(2))
  File "main.py", line 29, in require_odd
    _raise_exception(ValueError("n must be odd"))
  File "main.py", line 25, in _raise_exception
    raise exception
ValueError: n must be odd
```

Since the last line of code from the traceback is redundant, how do I raise the exception so that it shows the following?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(require_odd(2))
ValueError: n must be odd
```

---

Currently, I'm doing this:

```py
def _raise_exception(exception):
    try:
        raise exception
    except Exception as e:
        # Remove the last two calls (from this function and from the caller of this function)
        stack_lines = traceback.format_stack()[:-2]

        # Get the exception lines that contains the "Traceback (most recent call last):" in
        # the first line and the "ValueError: n must be odd" in the last line
        exception_lines = traceback.format_exception(e.__class__, e, e.__traceback__)

        # Join the relevant lines, print to stderr and exit
        print(''.join(exception_lines[:1] + stack_lines + exception_lines[-1:]), file=sys.stderr)
        exit(1)

def require_odd(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        _raise_exception(ValueError("n must be odd"))

print(require_odd(2))
```

which indeed prints

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(require_odd(2))
ValueError: n must be odd
```

But it just feels *ad hoc*. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "redundant" here. The stack trace is functions as one would hope - it is dumping the entire call stack. That is generally considered a *good thing* and the Python runtime goes through a lot of trouble to provide you that information...

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you eliminate the `_raise_exception` function?

If you just ran

```
if n % 2 == 0: 
    raise ValueError("n must be odd")
```

that would eliminate the last line, and an unecessary step in the process. It wouldn't eliminate the middle line, but generally, best practices (that I'm aware of) are to leave the stack alone. You want as much data as possible when something goes wrong.

Comment: As you said, this would add a `raise ValueError("n must be odd")` line, which I think is redundant since the last line of the exception is `ValueError: n must be odd`, but if there's no better option I think I'll have to deal with it.

Comment: It just seems like a lot of work to make something that isn't user facing "pretty." It is a bit redundant, but again, it's more information.
And if you're searching a longer stack for the error, having the redundancy will help catch your eye easier.